# How to beautify the HTML code in pycharm console?

Tags: html, pycharm, console

I make http requests with python, and when I receive the HTML file and print it on the console, it's very hard to read. Is there any package (like HtmlTidy for sublime) to beautify it?

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Currently, it looks like this]

I would like to make it look like this:
[image: I would like to make it look like this]